# What is the use of this `while False:` in Python's standard library?

Tags: cpython

CPython's implementation of [collections.abc.Iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Iterable) has this [bizarre idiom](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/13d44891426e0faf165f974f2e46907ab5b645a9/Lib/_collections_abc.py#L285):

```
while False:
    yield None
```

Seems like the second line will never be executed. So why not just use `pass` instead?

The full code for the `Iterable` class is as follows:

```
class Iterable(metaclass=ABCMeta):

    __slots__ = ()

    @abstractmethod
    def __iter__(self):
        while False:
            yield None

    @classmethod
    def __subclasshook__(cls, C):
        if cls is Iterable:
            return _check_methods(C, "__iter__")
        return NotImplemented

    __class_getitem__ = classmethod(GenericAlias)
```

Comment: The implementation [arrived in this commit](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/cd16bf640405065e4702539632ce577536207d88#diff-163c1525f292b112e15d4d78952fb8bc6a4b80e6ec8d608eea37edad2cfed28e), fully-formed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This idiom's use of `yield` means it will return an empty generator, as opposed to `None`:

```
>>> def iter():
...   if False:
...     yield None
... 
>>> iter()
<generator object iter at 0x7fd2cc134660>
>>> [i for i in iter()]
[]
```

If `pass` were used:

```
>>> def iter2():
...   pass
... 
>>> iter2()
>>> [i for i in iter2()]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

That `TypeError` is what is being avoided.